# Pygame mixer.music can't read mp3 stream

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mp3, audio-player

I am trying to make my own music player with Python, and after looking at alternatives, I've settled on using pygame's mixer.music to actually play the audio. (I've used pygame before, just usually for actual games) I was looking at playsound instead until I realized I needed a way to play the next song once one is done, as well as the ability to play and pause the audio. I also need to play mp3 files instead of the wavs that most alternatives require. 
I actually got it working perfectly originally, until I tried adding other unrelated features, and now it's saying:

```
File "main.py", line 66, in playCurrentSong
mixer.load(path.join(museDir, currentSong))
pygame.error: Error reading the stream. (code 18)
```

(`museDir` is my variable for the directory that music files are in, and `mixer` is my variable for `pygame.mixer.music` as a shorthand)

I cannot figure out for the life of me why it's giving me this error now, as it played the audio perfectly fine before. My code is here: https://pastebin.com/V7nAfmK6

If a solution only works on a certain operating system, my final OS will be Linux, on a Rasperry Pi, but I'm trying to write and test the code on Windows. However, if that's not possible, I understand.

Thank you beforehand for any and all help; this is giving me a headache.

Comment: What\s the name of the file you\re trying to load? Mp3 support is spotty in pygame if I'm not mistaken. You're probably better off using a solution more meant to play audio. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325794/how-to-play-music-through-python-with-mpg321/16326257#16326257 or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673746/playing-mp3-files-with-pyaudio/26759539#26759539?

Comment: I have a few different sample songs I'm using for testing, Move.mp3, Kidman Blues.mp3, Surrender.mp3, and a few others. I'll look into those links and see if they help.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the source of the problem.

Before the error popped up, I had been trying to mess around with the metadata of the mp3 files in order to incorporate a genre system into the player, but nothing was working. I eventually decided to use csv files for that instead.

I must have done something wrong however when I was messing around with that metadata because I looked at the mp3s in File Explorer, and they were all 0 bytes. That's why pygame couldn't read the stream: there wasn't one! I plugged the pygame stuff back in, replaced the mp3s with new ones, and it works just fine now.

Thanks for the help anyway though, Torxed!